# Run a compiled batch file (exe) file through a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem while starting compiled batch files to exe with the start command. It opens a fresh command line instead of a windows of the compiled batch file. There's the code:

```
start "Aether II AutoUpdater.exe"
```

The "Aether II AutoUpdater.exe" file is a compiled batch file.
When I execute this command, It will open the CMD.

How can I start the compiled batch file without opening the command line instead of the file?

Comment: I've never heard of a "compiled batch file".  Batch files are a list of commands interpreted by the command processor. I'm not aware of a way to compile them. Also, you should be able to just double-click any `.exe` file to run it (without arguments).

Comment: I'm making automatic updater and it won't work without a solution.

Comment: With little details I can only guess. However my first guess is that you do not have the full path to your "Aether II AutoUpdater.exe" For example "C:\MyFolder\Aether II AutoUpdater.exe"

Comment: Oh.. So how do I get the path to the folder where the file is?

Comment: I found it. This command gets the current folder the batch file is in: %~dp0
But it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an extremely common issue with the `start` command. Basically, the issue stems from the fact that start will always assume that the first set of quotes it encounters is supposed to be the window's title. To get around this, you can simply add another set of quotes:

```
start "" "Aether II AutoUpdater.exe"
```

If that doesn't work, you can also add the `/b` flag to start the application in the same window.

```
start "" /b "Aether II AutoUpdater.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Hope I will remember that :D.